# How do I open an image in a separate window using a button click in PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget, QFileDialog, QPushButton, QLineEdit,QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QDialog, QVBoxLayout
import Updated_encrypt
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = 'Encrypt/Decrypt'
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 300

        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.button1 = QPushButton('Encrypt')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.openSecondDialog)

        self.button2 = QPushButton('Decrypt')

        vbox.addWidget(self.button1)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button2)

        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.show()

    def openSecondDialog(self):
        hbox = QVBoxLayout()
        mydialog = QDialog(self)
        mydialog.show()

        self.button2 = QPushButton('Check Image')
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.getImage)
        hbox.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.show()

    def getImage(self):
         hbox = QHBoxLayout()
         file_Name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                                'OpenFile',
                                                '',
                                                '')
         image_path = file_Name[0]
         updatedImage = Updated_encrypt.decrypt(image_path, 123)
         pixmap = QPixmap(updatedImage)
         self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(pixmap))
         self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

I have my code set up to implement an algorithm to modify an image when my I select it from my pop up dialogue. What I am trying to accomplish is for the image to pop up in a separate window when I click the encrypt button. I can't seem to get anything to pop up in the separate window aside from the window itself. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least the following errors:

- The "hbox" created is being added to the window and not to the QDialog: `self.setLayout(hbox)`, it must be `mydialog.setLayout(hbox)`.
- Do not use the same name for 2 different objects as they can cause problems, in your case there are 2 QPushButton assigned to the variable "self.button2".
- You try to use the variable "self.label" but never believe it.

Considering the above we can make the following improvements:

- Use more descriptive names to easily distinguish their function.
- If you are going to have a window that has a different objective, it is better to create a class.

The above avoid the indicated problems, considering the above the solution is:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QFileDialog,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

import Updated_encrypt


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.load_image_btn = QPushButton("Check Image")
        self.load_image_btn.clicked.connect(self.load_image)

        self.image_lbl = QLabel()
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.load_image_btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.image_lbl)

    def load_image(self):
        image_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "OpenFile", "", "")
        if image_path:
            updatedImage = Updated_encrypt.decrypt(image_path, 123)
            pixmap = QPixmap(updatedImage)
            self.image_lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(pixmap))


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.title = "Encrypt/Decrypt"
        self.InitWindow()

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(200, 500, 400, 300)

        self.encrypt_btn = QPushButton("Encrypt")
        self.encrypt_btn.clicked.connect(self.openSecondDialog)

        self.decrypt_btn = QPushButton("Decrypt")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.encrypt_btn)
        vbox.addWidget(self.decrypt_btn)

    def openSecondDialog(self):

        dialog = Dialog(self)
        dialog.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thank you. I just recently started working with PyQt5 for my class project and I was having a lot of trouble implementing this. The guides on YouTube were not at all helpful.

Comment: @StephenAgbenu Recommendations: 1) Strengthen the basics by testing and understanding the examples on the internet. 2) Avoid using YT to learn because apart from having to wait to see the whole video (which should take 10 minutes on average you can replace it with a tutorial on a website that takes a few seconds).

Comment: One other question if you don't mind. After completing the action located inside the load image function, the Gui ends up crashing followed by a problem report for python pop up, how would I make it close just the second dialog instead of the second and the main dialog window?